# Yii CSRF Validation is showing 400 Error

Tags: php, yii, csrf, yii1.x

I have enabled `CSRF` in main.php

```
'request' => array(
    'enableCsrfValidation' => true,      
)
```

After enabling `CSRF`, all the links in my app are showing 400 (Bad Request). I have tried searching for the fix and did not find any. Am i missing anything? I am using YII 1.16

Comment: fix formatting, add tag

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a session started? The Yii-CSRF-Token is stored in the session

400 is the default error thrown by Yii if the token is invalid.

If you want to check more closely look at CHttpRequest.php -> validateCsrfToken

Comment: I was able to fix it myself. In ValidateCsrfToken function, i added one exit() after $valid = false; I am not sure if it is correct way